# Construct a function $ f \in L^1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ with $ f \notin L^2([a,b],\lambda)$ for all $a < b$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Construct a function $ f \in L^1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ with $ f \notin L^2([a,b],\lambda)$ for all $a < b$

There are Hints given that suggest that you should start by finding a function that satisfies: $ f \in L^1([a,b],\lambda)$ with $ f \notin L^2([a,b],\lambda)$. The second Hint was, that I should start to construct sequence first, with known Lemmas(maybe Fatou's lemma could be used).

I though that i could use the function $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ that I p-integrate over $k\in[0,1]$ and $j\in[0,1]$ but I dont really get a real Ansatz here.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714209/42969

Answer (score 4):

For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, define $f_a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-a}},&x\in(a,a+1],\\
0,&\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$

and observe that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert f_a(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^{a+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x-a}}=2,$$

while

$$\int_a^b\lvert f_a(x)\rvert^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-a}=\infty$$

for all $b>a$. Consider now an enumeration $\{q_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{f_{q_j}(x)}{2^j}.$$

Then

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\lvert f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^j}\int_\mathbb{R}f_{q_j}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^{j-1}}<\infty,$$

where we can interchange integral and sum by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but for any $a<b$, with $a\in\mathbb{Q}$,

$$\int_a^b\lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^b\left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{f_{q_j}(x)}{2^j}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\geq\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\int_a^b f_a(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\infty,$$

with $m$ so that $a=q_m$. By appoximating any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ by rationals, we can extend the above to when $a\in\mathbb{R}$. It follows that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but for all $a<b$, $f\notin L^2([a,b])$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i am kinda confused about the last part. If you rewrite $ \int_{a}^{b} \mid f(x) \mid ^2 dx$ why does the $\frac{1}{2^j}$ factor disappear

Comment: Ah, that was a typo actually, let me fix it @PaperZZ

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks again, it really helped!!!